# How to use ArrayList get() method in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I made a code using an `ArrayList (short[])` in Android Studio but when I use the `get()` method it always return the last data stored and I don't know why. I'm using two buttons, one execute `adquirir_audio()` just to store some values. The second one prints in the console the stored data using a for loop, but it always return the same values.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String TAG = "AudioClient";

//Instancia de elementos de la interfaz de usuario.
Button btniniciar;
Button btnfiltrar;
TextView  lblfiltro;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
RadioButton radioButton;

boolean grabar = false;

private static int BUFFER_SIZE2 =16;

public static short[] buffer_debug    = new short[BUFFER_SIZE2];

public List<short[]> datos_short = new ArrayList<>();


private Thread myThread;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Identificando componentes de la IU.
    radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup);
    btniniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIniciar);
    btnfiltrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFiltrar);
    lblfiltro = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblFiltro);

    lblfiltro.setText("Filtro: -- \n Orden: -- \n Fstop: --");

    btniniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            grabar = !grabar;
            btniniciar.setText(grabar == true? "parar" : "iniciar");
            if (grabar){
                adquirir_audio();

            }
            else{

            }
        }
    });

    btnfiltrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for(int i = 0; i < datos_short.size(); i++){
                Log.d(TAG, "Buffer guardado: "+i + Arrays.toString(datos_short.get(i)));
            }
        }
    });

}

public void adquirir_audio(){

    int dir = 0;
    int dir2 = 0;

    while (dir < 5) {

    buffer_debug[0] = (short) (dir2 * 16);
    buffer_debug[1] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 1);
    buffer_debug[2] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 2);
    buffer_debug[3] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 3);
    buffer_debug[4] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 4);
    buffer_debug[5] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 5);
    buffer_debug[6] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 6);
    buffer_debug[7] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 7);
    buffer_debug[8] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 8);
    buffer_debug[9] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 9);
    buffer_debug[10] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 10);
    buffer_debug[11] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 11);
    buffer_debug[12] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 12);
    buffer_debug[13] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 13);
    buffer_debug[14] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 14);
    buffer_debug[15] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 15);

    Log.d(TAG, "Buffer: " + dir2 + Arrays.toString(buffer_debug));

    datos_short.add(dir,buffer_debug);

    dir = dir + 1;
    dir2 = (dir2 + 1);}}}
```

And here is the console

[image]
Hope you can help me.

Comment: `buffer_debug` is always the same object. when you modify it, you modify the same object you had already inserted in your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java the `Arrays` are not a primitive type and you are always changing the same `buffer_debug` object in all elements of the `ArrayList`.

You can use something like:

```
public void adquirir_audio(){

        short[] buffer_debug;
      
        int dir = 0;
        int dir2 = 0;

        while (dir < 5) {

            //Initialize a new Array
            buffer_debug = new short[16];  //<---

            buffer_debug[0] = (short) (dir2 * 16);
            buffer_debug[1] = (short) (dir2 * 16 + 1);
            //...

            datos_short.add(dir,buffer_debug);
            //...
       
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array has only one element.

You are filling your array this way

```
public void adquirir_audio(){
    int dir = 0:
    //some code
    datos_short.add(dir,buffer_debug); //here you are inserting an element at 0 position, always
}
```

Try this

```
public void adquirir_audio(){
    int dir = 0:
    //some code
    datos_short.add(buffer_debug); //this will add a new element at the end
}
```

Comment: thaks for answering!! I've done it like this before but the result is the same always getting the last data stored. 
The variable"dir"  is incremented inside the while loop with "dir = dir+1;"

Comment: Ok, then put your dir variable outside the adquirir_audio method, just like datos_short is declared, and remove the line int dir = 0;

Comment: that's not what  `add` does. that function should actually be named "insert". There are indeed multiple elements in the list, this is not the issue